# How to integrating Proguard in a Tycho/Maven build workflow for Eclipse e4 RCP Application?

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, proguard, tycho

I am successfully using Tycho 0.22.0 with Maven 3.2.5 to build my Eclipse e4 RCP application according to this Lars Vogel tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html

I used ProGuard to obfuscate the results of the above build on my three plugin jars and I have a working proguard configuration file.

Now I would like integrate Proguard in my build process so the obfuscation takes place before packaging in zip files done by Tycho. Unfortunately my maven knowledge is really primitive so an example of how I could achieve the above would be very appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Did you achieved that? When yes, I would be thankful to see your solution.

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. I prioritized other things above this. Hopefully I'll read the maven book and do it in the next few months. If you beat me to it please share